# How SUSY solves the hierarchy problem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

I am struggling to understand the argument for why the introduction of a stop in SUSY can solve the hierarchy problem. The quadratic divergence from the top loop in the higgs mass calculation gives a contribution of
$$
\delta m_h^2 = - \frac{|y_f|^2}{16\pi^2} \left[2\Lambda^2 + \ldots \right]
$$
If we introduce a scalar $S$, there should be two additional diagrams to consider:

[image]

and

[image]

The first diagram should give a contribution like

$$
\delta m_h^2 = \frac{\lambda_S}{16\pi^2} \left[\Lambda^2 + \ldots \right]
$$

and the second like

$$
\delta m_h^2 = \frac{|\lambda_S|^2}{16\pi^2} \left[\Lambda^2 + \ldots \right]
$$

(I am probably off by some constants or something). Now, this seems to me to only cancel out of $y_f = \lambda_S = 1$, which is close to 1 for the top but not exact. Isn't this just another unnatural fine tuning problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are considering three loop diagrams with three couplings: $g_1$ for the Higgs-top Yukawa coupling, $g_2$ for the $h h f \tilde{f}$ coupling, and $g_3$ for the $h f \tilde{f}$ coupling. When you do the loop diagrams, the contribution is schematically $-g_1^2 + g_2 + g_3^2$.

You've pointed out that this is not zero for general values of $g_1$, $g_2$, and $g_3$, but of course it isn't! Without further structure, these couplings have nothing to do with each other. The point of supersymmetry is that it *does* relate the couplings -- and if you work through the calculations in detail, it relates $g_1$, $g_2$, and $g_3$ in exactly the way needed to make the $O(\Lambda^2)$ part of the loop integrals cancel out.

Comment: do you happen to know a good reference that shows the full calculation? I am trying to understand the details for my thesis.

Comment: @JacksonBurzynski An example of this kind of cancellation in a toy model is in section 5.2 of Aitchison. I'm sure that there must exist analogous explicit calculations for the full MSSM, but I don't study SUSY, so I don't know.